# remove selected items by clicking button at once -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, there is a list and with each item is having a checkbox. So, user can select multiple items by using checkboxes. There is one button called 'Remove Checked Items". If user click that button all the selected items will be removed from the list.

I have set the state for checked or selected items into a list by using id(mruCode is the id in my case). After that created one button event function where i am clearing the array.

selected/Checked items saving:

```
handleCheckedRemove(mruCode) {
        let rItems = [];
        let removeItems = this.state.configuredList.filter(obj => obj.mruCode === mruCode);
        console.log(removeItems);
        rItems = rItems.concat(removeItems);
        this.setState({
            chkitems: rItems
        });
    }
```

Button Event :

```
handleActionButton(){
        this.setState({chkitems:[]});
    }
```

Component Code:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[],
               chkitems:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedRemove = this.handleCheckedRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleActionButton = this.handleActionButton.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null && this.props.locationData!= undefined){
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
      }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData)){ 
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }

    //other codes
    configLocation(locationData){
        let configuredList =[];
        if(locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails !=undefined ){
            locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item=>{
                 let listitem ={...item};
                 configuredList.push(listitem);
            });
        }
        this.setState({configuredList},()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        }); 
    }
    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState({
            configuredList:this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails.filter((_,i)=>i!==index)
        },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        });

    }
   //other codes
    removeLocationAll(){
        this.setState({configuredList: []});
    }

    handleCheckedRemove(mruCode){
        let rItems = [];
        let removeItems = this.state.configuredList.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode===mruCode);
        rItems = rItems.concat(removeItems);
            this.setState({
                chkitems: rItems
            },()=>{
                console.log(this.state.chkitems);
            });
    }
    handleActionButton(){
        this.setState({chkitems:[]});
    }

    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}{index < this.state.configuredList.length-1 ?',\u00A0' : ''}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="submitSmallBtn2" onClick={()=>this.handleActionButton()}>Delete Checked</button><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.removeLocationAll()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><th><input type="checkbox" onClick={()=>this. handleCheckedRemove(locc.mruCode)} /><label></label></th><th className="text-left"><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead> </table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked:state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())},
        checkboxState:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(checkboxState(mruCode))},
        checkedLocation:()=>{dispatch(checkedLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

Button onClick event is not working. Suppose if i select two items. But console it is showing only one item in that list(chkItems).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use previous state to concat the new one,

```
handleCheckedRemove(mruCode){
  let removeItems = this.state.configuredList.filter(obj=>obj.mruCode===mruCode);
  this.setState(prevState=> {
     let rItems = prevState.chkitems;
     rItems.push(removeItems);
     return {chkitems:rItems}
  },()=>{
     console.log(this.state.chkitems);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..Yes it is merging now. But, in button event how to connect that so if click then chkItems list will be clear.

Comment: For clearing the `chkItems` we can do `this.setState({chkitems:[]});` on any click event.

Comment: How you are calling this?

Comment: onClick={()=>this.handleActionButton()} in button ...in function i have created above in my question

Comment: Just do this, `onClick={this.handleActionButton}`.

Comment: Yes... You are correct.  It is removing from chkItems list which is sublist of configuredList.  Button function not removing from configuredList.  I have tried a few things.  If you check my return part of component you can understand

Comment: What you want to remove?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this code, so that I can see the problem.